# Is such description of a stochastic process correct?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Say the stochastic process $\mathbf{x}_t=[1,x_{1,t},x_{2,t},\cdots,x_{n,t}]'$ is an $(n+1)\times 1$ vector. Now if the first element of the vector (i.e. the constant 1) was not there, I would have expressed this stochastic process as $\{\mathbf{x}_t:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n},t=0,1,\cdots\}$ defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. However, not sure since the constant $1$ is present it would be appropriate to write $\{\mathbf{x}_t:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1},t=0,1,\cdots\}$. I believe the former representation is still the correct one? If not, how would one express this ?

Comment: i'd call x - bona fide variables, and stick with the first approach, but 1 is a random variable too, it's just almost surely 1 :)

Comment: Your question is unclear: what do you mean by "express this" at the end?  BTW, by allowing that any constant (such as $1$) defines a random variable (namely, the constant function on $\Omega,$ which is Borel measurable), your concern seems to disappear.

Comment: represent I suppose? or perhaps span?